# Can we listen to stream value before material app Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I am trying to load a splash Screen before the app starts.

Splash screen will load as the user clicks on the app.

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<Users>(
      stream: AuthService().user,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return MaterialApp(home: Splash());
        } else {
          // Loading is done, return the app:
          return MaterialApp(
            home: Scaffold(body: Wrapper()),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

This is wrapper.dart

```
class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<Users>(context);
    print(user);
    //Return either home or authenticate widget
    return user == null ? Authenticate() : Home();
  }
}
```

This is splash.dart

```
class Splash extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        color: Colors.black,
        child: Center(
            child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: [
            Icon(
              Icons.movie,
              color: Colors.white,
              size: 30,
            ),
            Text(
              'Loading App',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30),
            ),
          ],
        )),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the stream from firebase:

```
class AuthService{
      final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    //Create User object based on FireBase
      Users _userFromFirebaseUser(User user) {
        return user != null ? Users(uid: user.uid) : null;
      }
    
      //auth change user stream
      Stream<Users> get user {
        return _auth.authStateChanges().map(_userFromFirebaseUser);
      }
}
```

Error:Could not find the correct `Provider<Users>` above this Wrapper Widget. But i am providing a Stream of Users in main.dart above warpper in MyApp class.

Comment: From the code you posted, in all your snippets, you have not defined your provider<User>, you are just attempting to consume or use it. For example ` final user = Provider.of<Users>(context);` is not defining it, but you care calling it.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually not providing Users, all you do is wrapping your code with StreamBuilder that listens to stream but it does not "provide" anything downstream. In order to provide value so it is accessed by provider you should use StreamProvider instead of StreamBuilder, see [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/StreamProvider-class.html) for documentation and [here](https://gist.github.com/jtlapp/0754502359435ca0de7eb25c39e0be70) for example

Comment: So we cannot access StreamBuilder value using provider?

Comment: No, I believe not.